# D5300 Autofocus

Tags: nikon, autofocus

I broke my 18-55 kit lens months ago. And i currently have no lens in my hand. But i usually hover over my camera setting for no reason. Tonight i charged my battery and then playing with the settings and noticed something changed

My nikon D5300 even with no lens used to be able to change Focus mode. Now it is black along with Focus Area and metering mode. My AF and AE lock button is set to AE. The problem is I can not acces my Focus mode (AF-A, AF-S etc). It's stuck at MF and live view shows the same. Why it is not accesable or changeable now? Is it a body problem?

Answer (score 2):

No. Your camera is just fine. Since there are fully manual lenses with no electrical contacts the camera doesnt know wether you attached such a lens or no lens at all. It does not make any sense to let you choose between any focus modes on manual lenses since they cant focus automatically. Thats why they disable the autofocus menu to suggest you that the camera cant do any focusing work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What practical difference does it make?
Without a lens attached nothing should work except full Manual mode.

[image]

<sup>Image from a D5500, but they are very similar.</sup>